# Flutter: How to push/pop navigator pages inside a Drawer?

Tags: navigation, flutter, drawer

The navigator doesn't have to be separated from the one running on my main page, just as long as I can push or pop pages **inside the drawer**.

Comment: when you say "inside the drawer" do you mean you want to keep the drawer open and re-render a new route, or that you want to navigate away from the parent page?  if the latter then all you have to do is pop then push.

Answer (score 0):

As I know default Drawer doesn't provide any way to do like this You should customise it by own widget *(Container widget)* and hide/show widget with animation whenever click on item.

Comment: With this method I can't make the back button work as I would want (it'd pop the drawer).  Is it possible to overwrite the back button with a function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this. However, I've managed to make push/pop work using a Drawer [here](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/flutter_navigation_drawer).